# Can i use html for addon gui?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need a button on addon bar and button on toolbar that redirect to some type of settings page(html,css,js) and this page can interact with main.js. Can it be done? If can, plz reccomend good tutorial.

Comment: for sdk method see the guys solution below. for non sdk, yes absolutely just put an iframe wherever and put the html into that. sdk uses same trick.

Comment: @Notidart Is there any simlpe way to add toolbar button with some menu items that show settings page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add button: use [widget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/widget), [ActionButton or ToggleButton](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui).
Settings page(html,css,js):use [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod).
Interact with main.js:use [port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/using_port) or [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/using_postMessage)

Here is an example:
main.js:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
const data = require("sdk/self").data;

var optionsPage = pageMod.PageMod({
    include: data.url("options.html"),
    contentScriptFile: data.url("options.js"),
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on("callMain",function(msg){
            console.log("callMain: " + msg);
        });
    }
});
var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "justForTest",
    label: "justForTest",
    contentURL: data.url("widget.png"),
    onClick: function(){
        tabs.open(data.url("options.html"));
    }
});
```

options.js:

```
self.port.emit("callMain", "from options.js");
```

Comment: Australis too new to use it, how to make toolbar button without it?

Comment: Widget is not Australis, you can use it now and change to ActionButton or ToggleButton in the future. But if you want to add context menu to the button, I think addon-sdk is not a good way. You'd better use xul.